# mysql pivot table with string values

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, pivot-table, aggregate

I have a table with just two columns like this

```
mysql> select * from stuff_table;
+------+-------+
| name | stuff |
+------+-------+
| John | shoes |
| Jim  | bag   |
| Ely  | book  |
| Tom  | bag   |
| Will | shoes |
| Pitt | book  |
| Dean | bag   |
| Luke | bag   |
+------+-------+
```

and I tried with many solutions I found like

```
select distinct
max(case when stuff='shoes' then name else name is null) end as shoes,
max(case when stuff='bag' then name else name is null end) as bag,
max(case when stuff='book' then name else name is null end) as book
from stuff_table;
```

but I just got this

```
+-------+------+------+
| shoes | bag  | book |
+-------+------+------+
| Will  | Tom  | Pitt |
+-------+------+------+
```

Instead, I want to get this

```
+-------+------+------+
| shoes | bag  | book |
+-------+------+------+
| John  | Jim  | Ely  |
| Will  | Tom  | Pitt |
| NULL  | Dean | NULL |
| NULL  | Luke | NULL |
+-------+------+------+
```

I have tried with sum(case...) or if(case..) or group by too but it doesn't work. Is there any mysql query to get such that table? Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: Your sample table is missing a column which would tell to which row in the pivoted output each data point would map.  Translation: there isn't enough information to answer this.

Comment: This is a kind of problem that is much easier to solve in an application language, not SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the version of `mysql` you are using, here's one approach establishing a `row_number` per group, then using `conditional aggregation` grouped by that row number:

```
select 
    rn, 
    max(case when stuff = 'bag' then name end) 'bag',
    max(case when stuff = 'book' then name end) 'book',
    max(case when stuff = 'shoes' then name end) 'shoes' 
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by stuff order by name) rn
  from stuff_table
) t
group by rn
```

- [Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/skbKMWPCGJFLURLmkcouD4/0)

---

Since you are using an older version of `mysql`, you'll need to use `user-defined variables` to establish the row number.  The rest then works the same.  Here's an example:

```
select 
    rn, 
    max(case when stuff = 'bag' then name end) 'bag',
    max(case when stuff = 'book' then name end) 'book',
    max(case when stuff = 'shoes' then name end) 'shoes' 
from (
  select *, 
  ( case stuff 
         when @curStuff
         then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
         else @curRow := 1 and @curStuff := stuff 
   end
  ) + 1 AS rn
  from stuff_table, (select @curRow := 0, @curStuff := '') r
  order by stuff
) t
group by rn
```

- [More Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/skbKMWPCGJFLURLmkcouD4/1)

Comment: what mysql version did you use? I used mysql 5.7

Comment: @Yarp As I mentioned, older versions of `mysql` don't support `row_number`.  You need to use `user-defined variables` instead.  Here's a working fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/skbKMWPCGJFLURLmkcouD4/1

Comment: What specific version what used for the first solution? It looks more elegant.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to use else  and You have a end outside of max function :

```
select distinct
max(case when stuff='shoes' then name end ) as shoes,
max(case when stuff='bag' then name  end) as bag,
max(case when stuff='book' then name  end) as book
from stuff_table;
```

Comment: My bad, the one that I posted return NULL but with eight rows. I just mixed up with so many solutions but didn't find a suitable one

Comment: it works but return the same number of rows as the first table where I want only four rows at max